# Spotify embedded control causes IE 11 to crash

Tags: internet-explorer, spotify

The Spotify embedded player is causing internet explorer 11 (11.0.10240.16590) to crash on windows 10.  This appears to have just started happening in the last few days (11/20/2015).

A direct copy of a song's embed code from the apotify player will cause this behavior, a specific example is here: https://www.music4dance.net/spotify.html

```
<iframe src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify%3Atrack%3A2VPZMOVWSPVz7AQQj2KcXJ" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

This doesn't reproduce on Chrome, Edge, Firefox or Opera. It does reproduce on multiple machines under IE, although occasionally I have to refresh the page once or twice to get the crash to reproduce.

Anyone else seeing this?

Callstack for IE at the point of the crash:

> jscript9.dll!Js::InlinedFrameWalker::FromPhysicalFrame(class Js::InlinedFrameWalker &,class Js::X86StackFrame &,class Js::ScriptFunction *) Unknown
>       jscript9.dll!Js::JavascriptStackWalker::UpdateFrame()   Unknown
>       jscript9.dll!Js::JavascriptExceptionOperators::WalkStackForExceptionContextInternal()   Unknown
>       jscript9.dll!Js::JavascriptExceptionOperators::WalkStackForExceptionContext(class Js::ScriptContext &,class Js::JavascriptExceptionContext &,void *,unsigned __int64,void *,bool)   Unknown
>       jscript9.dll!Js::JavascriptExceptionOperators::ThrowExceptionObjectInternal()   Unknown
>       jscript9.dll!Js::JavascriptExceptionOperators::Throw(void *,class Js::ScriptContext *)  Unknown
>       jscript9.dll!Js::JavascriptError::ThrowError()  Unknown
>       jscript9.dll!Js::JavascriptError::MapAndThrowError()    Unknown
>       jscript9.dll!Js::JavascriptError::MapAndThrowError(class Js::ScriptContext *,long)  Unknown
>       jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::InterpreterThunk<1>()   Unknown
>       0cec06f1()  Unknown
>       [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing]
>       jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::Process()   Unknown
>       jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::OP_TryCatch()   Unknown
>       jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::Process()   Unknown
>       jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::InterpreterThunk<1>()   Unknown
>       0cec06f1()  Unknown
>       jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::Process()   Unknown
>       jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::OP_TryCatch()   Unknown
>       jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::Process()   Unknown
>       jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::InterpreterThunk<1>()   Unknown
>       0cec06f1()  Unknown
>       jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::Process()   Unknown
>       jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::InterpreterThunk<1>()   Unknown
>       0cec0709()  Unknown
>       0d5b294d()  Unknown
>       jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::Process()   Unknown
>       jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::InterpreterThunk<1>()   Unknown
>       0cec0791()  Unknown
>       jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::Process()   Unknown
>       jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::InterpreterThunk<1>()   Unknown
>       0cec08a9()  Unknown
>       jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::Process()   Unknown
>       jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::InterpreterThunk<1>()   Unknown
>       0cec08f1()  Unknown
>       jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::Process()   Unknown
>       jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::InterpreterThunk<1>()   Unknown
>       0cec08f9()  Unknown
>       jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::Process()   Unknown
>       jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::InterpreterThunk<1>()   Unknown
>       0cec0901()  Unknown
>       jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::Process()   Unknown
>       jscript9.dll!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::InterpreterThunk<1>()   Unknown
>       0cec0909()  Unknown
>       jscript9.dll!Js::JavascriptFunction::CallFunction<1>()  Unknown
>       jscript9.dll!Js::JavascriptFunction::CallRootFunction() Unknown
>       jscript9.dll!ScriptSite::CallRootFunction() Unknown
>       jscript9.dll!ScriptSite::Execute()  Unknown
>       jscript9.dll!ScriptEngineBase::Execute()    Unknown
>       mshtml.dll!CListenerDispatch::InvokeVar()   Unknown
>       mshtml.dll!CListenerDispatch::Invoke()  Unknown
>       mshtml.dll!CEventMgr::_InvokeListeners()    Unknown
>       mshtml.dll!CEventMgr::Dispatch()    Unknown
>       mshtml.dll!CEventMgr::DispatchEvent(struct PROPERTYDESC_BASIC const *,class CBase *,class CSecurityContext *,long)  Unknown
>       mshtml.dll!CDocument::Fire_HTML5onreadystatechange(void)    Unknown
>       mshtml.dll!CMarkup::SetHTML5ReadyState()    Unknown
>       mshtml.dll!CMarkup::OnLoadStatusParseDone() Unknown
>       mshtml.dll!CMarkup::OnLoadStatus()  Unknown
>       mshtml.dll!CProgSink::DoUpdate()    Unknown
>       mshtml.dll!CProgSink::OnMethodCall(unsigned long)   Unknown
>       mshtml.dll!GlobalWndOnMethodCall()  Unknown
>       mshtml.dll!GlobalWndProc()  Unknown
>       user32.dll!__InternalCallWinProc@20()  Unknown
>       user32.dll!_UserCallWinProcCheckWow@36()   Unknown
>       user32.dll!_DispatchMessageWorker@8()  Unknown
>       user32.dll!_DispatchMessageW@4()   Unknown
>       ieframe.dll!CTabWindow::_TabWindowThreadProc()  Unknown
>       ieframe.dll!LCIETab_ThreadProc()    Unknown
>       iertutil.dll!_IsoThreadProc_WrapperToReleaseScope() Unknown
>       kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12() Unknown
>       ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart()    Unknown
>       ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8() Unknown